# change the parent view when it is collapsed and expanded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Please, anybody guide me how to create collapse and expand layouts like in the images I uploaded.

I used collapsed tool bar layout but it is collapsing completely. Please check the images for my issue

This is Collapsed view

[image: Collapsed view]

This is Expanded view

[image: Expanded view]